# How can i remove chunk.js and get back the source file name in the console log from chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, console.log

[image: how it is shown on google chrome]

[image: how is is shown on firefox]

the first image is from google chrome and the second is from firefox.

How can i make google chrome work normally again?

I want to get on google chrome, profile.js:154 instead of 17.chunk.js:491

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Zrna this is Juha's solution, i tried it now and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/61537016/6274504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. Open up the console
2. Press F1
3. Scroll down and press "Restore defaults and reload"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just tried it and it worked. Thank you soo muchh!